# Display block && none duplicate issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html `table` which has Name, Monthly Income and Income. I wrote a simple function that takes the values of the `<tds>` but only the Monthly Income and Income. If they are both 0 with one click hide the all the `<tr>`, and if you want you can show the `<tr>` again..
My code works fine. THE PROBLEM is, when i press hide and then show.. it is returning me an abnormal result of the specific `<tr>` i seriously don't know why..

```js
function hideZeros() {
  let trs, tds, td1, td2, total, i;

  trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 1; i < trs.length; i++) {

    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    td1 = parseInt(tds[1].innerHTML);
    td2 = parseInt(tds[2].innerHTML);

    total = (td1 + td2);

    if (total === 0) {
      if (trs[i].style.display === "none") {
        trs[i].style.display = "block";

      } else {
        trs[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Monthly Income</th>
    <th>Income</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jim</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td>100.000</td>
      <td>50.000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="hideZeros()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Can you paste it as a snippet?

Comment: Is there a reason why you reconstruct the "function scope" of `var` variables with `let`?

Comment: @Andreas, what do you mean by `reconstruct` ? I should use var instead of let ?

Comment: No, absolutely not! But variables should be as "local" as possible, hence the question why you define `i`, `tds`, `td1`and `td2` outside the loop when they are only used in the loop.

Comment: @Andreas, so you are saying i should `let tds, td1, td2, total;` inside the loop

Comment: `for (let i = 0; ... )`, `let tds = trs[i]...`, `let td1 = ...`, ... (you're not using `total` for anything else but the `if` condition, therefor I would remove it -> `if (td1 + td2 === 0) { ... }`)

Comment: @Andreas, you are right my friend thank you for correction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `display` value for a `<tr>` is `table-row` not `block`.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, i changed it on my function and it works perfectly, i am accepting your answer in 8 minutes

Comment: you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @dehart By 4 minutes, so why the answer at all ;)

Comment: I spent 4 minutes finding out what's wrong. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default the style of a `tr` element is not "block" but "table-row"